# JavaScript fire Event on selection of some of the option

Tags: javascript, events

JavaScript fire Event on the selection of some of the option selection.
Example: I have 4 options (1. Option A, 2. Option B, 3.Option C, 4.Option D, Option E), if I select options (2 or 3 ) then the event should fire. However, nothing should happen on the selection of other options.

Html:

```js
var selectElem = document.getElementById('select')
var pElem = document.getElementById('p')

// When a new <option> is selected
selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var index = selectElem.selectedIndex;
  // Add that data to the <p>
  pElem.innerHTML = 'selectedIndex: ' + index;
})
```

```html
<p id="p">selectedIndex: 0</p>

<select id="select">
  <option selected>Option A</option>
  <option>Option B</option>
  <option>Option C</option>
  <option>Option D</option>
  <option>Option E</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are doing and where it's going wrong? If i understand correctly though you want to use some kind of on change function, then check the value of current selected option matching it to the ones that fire this event of yours.

Comment: Yes, please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that **event should fire**. 
If you consider **event** as a simple **function** call then following code is working fine.

If you really meant to fire a custom event then just use these two lines in the if check

```
// Create the event
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", { "detail": "Example of an event" });

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Complete code for you:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <p id="idIndex">selectedIndex: 0</p>

        <select id="idSelect">
            <option selected>Option A</option>
            <option>Option B</option>
            <option>Option C</option>
            <option>Option D</option>
            <option>Option E</option>
        </select>
        </br>

        <script>
            var selectElem  = document.getElementById('idSelect')
            var indexElem   = document.getElementById('idIndex')

            // When a new <option> is selected
            selectElem.addEventListener('change', function() {

                // Get selected index
                var index = selectElem.selectedIndex;

                // Add selected index to the <p>
                indexElem.innerHTML = 'selectedIndex: ' + index;

                // If index selected is your desired index
                if ( index === 2 || index == 3 ) {
                    // Call your desired function here or trigger event
                    console.log("Call the function needed");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```